# Better way to map Kotlin data objects to data objects

Tags: java, kotlin, modelmapper

I want to convert/map some "data" class objects to similar "data" class objects. For example, classes for web form to classes for database records.

```
data class PersonForm(
    val firstName: String,
    val lastName: String,
    val age: Int,
    // maybe many fields exist here like address, card number, etc.
    val tel: String
)
// maps to ...
data class PersonRecord(
    val name: String, // "${firstName} ${lastName}"
    val age: Int, // copy of age
    // maybe many fields exist here like address, card number, etc.
    val tel: String // copy of tel
)
```

I use ModelMapper for such works in Java, but it can't be used because data classes are final (ModelMapper creates CGLib proxies to read mapping definitions). We can use ModelMapper when we make these classes/fields open, but we must implement features of "data" class manually.
(cf. ModelMapper examples: https://github.com/jhalterman/modelmapper/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/modelmapper/gettingstarted/GettingStartedExample.java)

How to map such "data" objects in Kotlin?

**Update:**
ModelMapper automatically maps fields that have same name (like tel -> tel) without mapping declarations. I want to do it with data class of Kotlin.

**Update:**
The purpose of each classes depends on what kind of application, but these are probably placed in the different layer of an application.

For example:

- data from database (Database Entity) to data for HTML form (Model/View Model)
- REST API result to data for database

These classes are similar, but are not the same.

I want to avoid normal function calls for these reasons:

- It depends on the order of arguments. A function for a class with many fields that have same type (like String) will be broken easily.
- Many declarations are nesessary though most mappings can be resolved with naming convention.

Of course, a library that has similar feature is intended, but information of the Kotlin feature is also welcome (like spreading in ECMAScript).

Comment: Please describe how you want to use the mapped classes. What is the purpose of having two separate data formats?

Comment: Never heard of duplication the data model (except for cases of legacy code). Usually the data you are working with (View Model) **is** the data you put into the database.

Comment: @voddan one use case would be to expose only parts of the domain model to different API consumers. Having separate DTO per _view_ of domain model is much cleaner than using i.e. [JsonView](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.1/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonView.html) IMHO

Comment: Do you really need these classes to be data classes?

Answer (score 95):

1. Simplest (best?):

   ```
   fun PersonForm.toPersonRecord() = PersonRecord(
           name = "$firstName $lastName",
           age = age,
           tel = tel
   )
   ```
2. Reflection (not great performance):

   ```
   fun PersonForm.toPersonRecord() = with(PersonRecord::class.primaryConstructor!!) {
       val propertiesByName = PersonForm::class.memberProperties.associateBy { it.name }
       callBy(args = parameters.associate { parameter ->
           parameter to when (parameter.name) {
               "name" -> "$firstName $lastName"
               else -> propertiesByName[parameter.name]?.get(this@toPersonRecord)
           }
       })
   }
   ```
3. Cached reflection (okay performance but not as fast as #1):

   ```
   open class Transformer<in T : Any, out R : Any>
   protected constructor(inClass: KClass<T>, outClass: KClass<R>) {
       private val outConstructor = outClass.primaryConstructor!!
       private val inPropertiesByName by lazy {
           inClass.memberProperties.associateBy { it.name }
       }

       fun transform(data: T): R = with(outConstructor) {
           callBy(parameters.associate { parameter ->
               parameter to argFor(parameter, data)
           })
       }

       open fun argFor(parameter: KParameter, data: T): Any? {
           return inPropertiesByName[parameter.name]?.get(data)
       }
   }

   val personFormToPersonRecordTransformer = object
   : Transformer<PersonForm, PersonRecord>(PersonForm::class, PersonRecord::class) {
       override fun argFor(parameter: KParameter, data: PersonForm): Any? {
           return when (parameter.name) {
               "name" -> with(data) { "$firstName $lastName" }
               else -> super.argFor(parameter, data)
           }
       }
   }

   fun PersonForm.toPersonRecord() = personFormToPersonRecordTransformer.transform(this)
   ```
4. [Storing Properties in a Map](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#storing-properties-in-a-map)

   ```
   data class PersonForm(val map: Map<String, Any?>) {
       val firstName: String   by map
       val lastName: String    by map
       val age: Int            by map
       // maybe many fields exist here like address, card number, etc.
       val tel: String         by map
   }

   // maps to ...
   data class PersonRecord(val map: Map<String, Any?>) {
       val name: String    by map // "${firstName} ${lastName}"
       val age: Int        by map // copy of age
       // maybe many fields exist here like address, card number, etc.
       val tel: String     by map // copy of tel
   }

   fun PersonForm.toPersonRecord() = PersonRecord(HashMap(map).apply {
       this["name"] = "${remove("firstName")} ${remove("lastName")}"
   })
   ```

Comment: MapStruct with `@KotlinBuilder` is a beautiful and fast solution. See other answer (where I've added `@KotlinBuilder` info).

Comment: Actually I've stopped using MapStruct now, and just go with the first solution mentioned, ie. manual mapping. MapStruct is java-based, so does not give null-safety. Also I find I get compile-time safety anyway with simple kotlin initializer, when there are no default values on constructor. So if a field is added on the data object, I get a compile error, which is what I want.

Answer (score 27):

Is this are you looking for?

```
data class PersonRecord(val name: String, val age: Int, val tel: String){       
    object ModelMapper {
        fun from(form: PersonForm) = 
            PersonRecord(form.firstName + form.lastName, form.age, form.tel)           
    }
}
```

and then:

```
val personRecord = PersonRecord.ModelMapper.from(personForm)
```

Comment: The operation that you write is I wanted to do. But I want to reduce mapping declarations because many fields that have same names (like tel -> tel) exist. I want to write only special rules like firstName + lastName => name.

Answer (score 22):

MapStruct lets kapt generate classes doing the mapping (without reflection).

Use MapStruct:

```
@Mapper
interface PersonConverter {

    @Mapping(source = "phoneNumber", target = "phone")
    fun convertToDto(person: Person) : PersonDto

    @InheritInverseConfiguration
    fun convertToModel(personDto: PersonDto) : Person

}


// Note this either needs empty constructor or we need @KotlinBuilder as dsecribe below
data class Person: this(null, null, null, null) (...)
```

Use:

```
val converter = Mappers.getMapper(PersonConverter::class.java) // or PersonConverterImpl()

val person = Person("Samuel", "Jackson", "0123 334466", LocalDate.of(1948, 12, 21))

val personDto = converter.convertToDto(person)
println(personDto)

val personModel = converter.convertToModel(personDto)
println(personModel)
```

Edit:

Now with @KotlinBuilder for avoiding constructor() issue:

[GitHub: Pozo's mapstruct-kotlin](https://github.com/Pozo/mapstruct-kotlin)

Annotate data classes with `@KotlinBuilder`. This will create a  `PersonBuilder` class, which MapStruct uses, thus we avoid ruining the interface of the data class with a constructor().

```
@KotlinBuilder
data class Person(
    val firstName: String,
    val lastName: String,
    val age: Int,
    val tel: String
)
```

Dependency :

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.pozo/mapstruct-kotlin
api("com.github.pozo:mapstruct-kotlin:1.3.1.1")
kapt("com.github.pozo:mapstruct-kotlin-processor:1.3.1.1")
```

https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/tree/master/mapstruct-kotlin

Comment: You forgot to mention "tiny" detail. Your data classes have to be mutable and you have to have custom constructor of  `constructor() : this(null, null, null, null)`. So until mapstruct team comes up with proper kotlin support, I'd avoid using it and go with manual conversion as @mfulton26 mentioned in his first solution.

Comment: I would also recommend MapStruct since it doesn't use reflection and is thus faster. For the constructor issue you can use this extension https://github.com/Pozo/mapstruct-kotlin which allows you to use the builder approach not requiring the constructor() : this(null, null) fiasco anymore

Answer (score 8):

Using [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/)

```
/** Util.kt **/

class MapperDto() : ModelMapper() {
    init {
        configuration.matchingStrategy = MatchingStrategies.LOOSE
        configuration.fieldAccessLevel = Configuration.AccessLevel.PRIVATE
        configuration.isFieldMatchingEnabled = true
        configuration.isSkipNullEnabled = true
    }
}

object Mapper {
    val mapper = MapperDto()

    inline fun <S, reified T> convert(source: S): T = mapper.map(source, T::class.java)
}
```

Usage

```
val form = PersonForm(/** ... **/)
val record: PersonRecord = Mapper.convert(form)
```

You might need some mapping rules if the field names differ. See [the getting started](http://modelmapper.org/getting-started/)
PS: Use `kotlin no-args` plugin for having default no-arg constructor with your data classes

Answer (score 4):

Do you really want a separate class for that? You can add properties to the original data class:

```
data class PersonForm(
    val firstName: String,
    val lastName: String,
    val age: Int,
    val tel: String
) {
    val name = "${firstName} ${lastName}"
}
```

Comment: A spearate class is not required nesessarilly. But I want to avoid depending on the order of arguments.

Comment: @sunnyone You can always use [named arguments](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#named-arguments) when constructing your data objects so that you don't depend on the order the arguments are defined in.

Answer (score 4):

This works using Gson:

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> Any.mapTo(): T =
    GsonBuilder().create().run {
        toJson(this@mapTo).let { fromJson(it, T::class.java) }
    }

fun PersonForm.toRecord(): PersonRecord =
    mapTo<PersonRecord>().copy(
        name = "$firstName $lastName"
    )

fun PersonRecord.toForm(): PersonForm =
    mapTo<PersonForm>().copy(
        firstName = name.split(" ").first(),
        lastName = name.split(" ").last()
    )
```

with not nullable values allowed to be null because Gson uses [sun.misc.Unsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45793451/kotlin-not-nullable-value-can-be-null)..

Comment: Gson is quite sluggish

Answer (score 3):

For ModelMapper you could use [Kotlin's no-arg compiler plugin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#no-arg-compiler-plugin), with which you can create an annotation that marks your data class to get a synthetic no-arg constructor for libraries that use reflection. Your data class needs to use `var` instead of `val`.

```
package com.example

annotation class NoArg

@NoArg
data class MyData(var myDatum: String)

mm.map(. . ., MyData::class.java)
```

and in build.gradle (see docs for Maven):

```
buildscript {
  . . .
  dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
  }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin-noarg'

noArg {
  annotation "com.example.NoArg"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use ModelMapper to map to a Kotlin data class.  The keys are:

- Use @JvmOverloads (generates a constructor with no arguments)
- Default values for data class member
- Mutable member, var instead of val

  > ```
  > data class AppSyncEvent @JvmOverloads constructor(
  >     var field: String = "",
  >     var arguments: Map<String, *> = mapOf<String, Any>(),
  >     var source: Map<String, *> = mapOf<String, Any>()
  > )
  >
  > val event = ModelMapper().map(request, AppSyncEvent::class.java)
  > ```

Answer (score 1):

[LaMapper](https://github.com/labai/la-utils/tree/main/la-mapper#la-mapper) - is mapper for Kotlin, supports both - constructor parameters and properties mapping.

It uses bytecode generation at runtime, so performance is the same as handwritten code. No compiler plugins are required.

Example

```kotlin
fun PersonForm.toPersonRecord(): PersonRecord = LaMapper.copyFrom(this) {
    PersonRecord::code from PersonForm::personCode // property mapping
    PersonRecord::name from { "${it.firstName} ${it.lastName}" } // lambda mapping
    // all other properties are mapped by name
}

val rec = person.toPersonRecord()
```

In addition it has various data-type conversions by default (numbers, dates, enums etc.).

And, as it uses property references instead of strings for fields, it is more safe for refactoring.

---

Disclaimer: I'm the author.

Answer (score 1):

[kMapper](https://github.com/s0nicyouth/kmapper)-object to object mapper specifically created for Kotlin. Uses compile time code generation, so no reflection.
Interface description for a mapper looks like that:

```
@Mapper
internal interface BindMapper {
    fun map(dto: BindDto, @Bind second: Int, @Bind third: SomeInternalDto, @Bind(to = "fourth") pr: Double): BindDomain
}
```

More examples [here](https://github.com/s0nicyouth/kmapper/tree/master/testload/src/main/kotlin/com/syouth/kmapper/testload).

Disclaimer: I'm the author.

Comment: Looks promising, but please add a disclaimer, that you are the author of kmapper

Answer (score 1):

Try this kotlin library, it support both kotlin and java

https://github.com/krud-dev/shapeshift

Answer (score 1):

You can use `kotlin extension` function for transfer/convert one object to another object

**Example:**

```
data class PersonForm(
    val firstName: String? = null, 
    val lastName: String? = null, 
    val age: Int? = null,
    // maybe many fields exist here like address, card number, etc.
    val tel: String? = null
)

// maps to ...
data class PersonRecord(
    val name: String? = null, 
    val age: Int? = null, 
    val tel: String
)
```

Now create kotlin extension function for Convert / transfer into `PersonRecord`

```
fun PersonForm.transform(): PersonRecord {
    val name: String = this.firstName + " " + this.lastName
    val age: Int? = this.age
    val tel: String = this.tel.toString()
    return PersonRecord(name, age, tel)
}
```

and now you will be able to use it

```
fun getInfo() {
    val personrecord = PersonForm().transform()
    val finalName = personrecord.name  // This will be first name and last name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DataClassMapper` class taken from here: https://github.com/jangalinski/kotlin-dataclass-mapper

```
data class PersonForm(
    val firstName: String,
    val lastName: String,
    val age: Int,
    // maybe many fields exist here like address, card number, etc.
    val tel: String
)

// maps to ...
data class PersonRecord(
    val name: String, // "${firstName} ${lastName}"
    val age: Int, // copy of age
    // maybe many fields exist here like address, card number, etc.
    val tel: String // copy of tel
)

fun mapPerson(person: PersonForm): PersonRecord =
    DataClassMapper<PersonForm, PersonRecord>()
        .targetParameterSupplier(PersonRecord::name) { "${it.firstName} ${it.lastName}"}
        .invoke(person)

fun main() {
    val result = mapPerson(PersonForm("first", "last", 25, "tel"))
    println(result)
}
```

Result will be:

```
PersonRecord(name=first last, age=25, tel=tel)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way ever to use `ModelMapper` in `Kotlin`, no need for `Converters` or `TypeMappers`. just use `.apply{}` extension function on the converted object:

```
modelmapper.map(myDTO, myEntity::clas.java).apply{
    myDTO.bar = foo(myEntity.bar)
}
```

below applys to the problem:

```
data class PersonRecord(
    var name: String? = null,
    var age: Int? = null,
    var tel: String? = null,
) {
    companion object {
        fun fromForm(personForm: PersonForm): PersonRecord = ModelMapper().map(personForm, PersonRecord::class.java)
            .apply {
                name = "${personForm.firstName} ${personForm.lastName}"
            }
    }
}
```