# Kotlin modelMapper, Int to Float

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, modelmapper

I use kotlin/springboot and I want to use `ModelMapper` to map to Data Classes. I want to map `Account:balance:Amount:Int` to `AccountDto:balance:Float`

From :

```
data class Account(
        val id: String,
        var balance: Amount
)

data class Amount(var value: Int)
```

To :

```
data class AccountDto(
        var id: String,
        var balance: Float?)
```

I tried this :

```
val modelMapper = ModelMapper()

modelMapper.addMappings(object : PropertyMap<Account, AccountDto>() {
    override fun configure() {
        map(source.balance.value / 100f, destination.balance)
    }
})
```

but I have error like that :

```
Caused by: org.modelmapper.ConfigurationException: ModelMapper configuration errors:

1) Cannot map final type ....accounts.Account.

2) Cannot map final method ....accounts.Account.getBalance().

3) Cannot map final type ....accounts.Amount.

4) Cannot map final method ....accounts.Amount.getValue().

5) Cannot map final type ....account.dto.AccountDto.

6) Cannot map final method ....account.dto.AccountDto.getBalance().
```

I have no more idea right now.

Comment: Check out this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39199426/better-way-to-map-kotlin-data-objects-to-data-objects

Answer (score 0):

Change `val` to `var`

```kotlin
data class Account(
        val id: String,
        var balance: Amount
)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, You must make your DTO variables nullable.

Use `apply{}` extension function to do all conversions you need, check the code below

```
data class AccountDTO(
    var id: String? = null,
    var balance: Float? = null,
){
    companion object{
        fun fromEntity(account: Account): AccountDTO = ModelMapper().map(account, AccountDTO::class.java)
            .apply {
            balance = account.balance.value.toFloat()
        }
    }
}
```